# Destroying tkinter figures with keyboard interrupt in a embedded c++ python editor

Tags: c++, python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I am addind a python editor to a C++ application. In order to be able to stop the python process when the user presses ctrl-c, I have 2 threads:

1- the first one runs the python string;

2- the second one polls the keyboard to check for a keyboard interupt.

I use microsoft concurrency library to create the threads:

```
auto task1 = Concurrency::make_task([&] 
{
    task1_id = GetCurrentThreadId();
    Run(Script);
    bFinish = true;
});

auto task2 = Concurrency::make_task([&] 
{
    while(true)
    {
        if ((GetKeyState (0x43) < 0 && (GetKeyState (VK_CONTROL) < 0)) && task1_id != 0)
        {
            PyGILState_STATE gstate;
            gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
            int t = PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(task1_id,PyExc_KeyboardInterrupt);
            PyGILState_Release(gstate);
            break;
        }
        else if(bFinish)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Sleep(10);
        }
    }
});

m_tasks.run(task2);
Concurrency::task_group_status test = m_tasks.run_and_wait(task1);
```

This usually works pretty well. If a ctrl-c event happens, a keyboardinterrupt event will happend on the 'script thread' and everything will stop.

A problem happends when I use matplotlib to create some figure, and send a ctrl-c event while the figures are still open. The event will stop everything like before, but the tkinter windows will not be destroyed and clicking on them will give a run time error:

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
```

Is there any way I could force those windows to be properly destroyed by the keybordinterrupt exception?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you are getting at least one more thread from the gui event loop that you need to clean up.  Have a look at the code in https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/master/lib/matplotlib/backends to see how to programtically kill the TK windows.

Comment: Thanks for your feeback tcaswell. I know I could parse the code to see if there is a plt.show() call then try to run some code when ctrl-c is pressed to properly destroy everything, but this is not what I want to do. I want to be able to run a script and cancel it properly whatever code is in there. If I start adding 'special case' for matplotlib, I'll probably going to have to add special case to a lot of other libraries. My guess is that I am not destroying the things properly... but i don't know how.

Comment: I looked at spyder source code ( because it seems to work great with this editor) and they seem to be using PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc as well....

Comment: in backend_tkagg.py, the function show() start with the comment:
        this function doesn't segfault but causes the
        PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL state bug on win32

Comment: well, this is now _way_ out of my area of knowing what I am talking about.  Good luck!